# Artboards are sitting on top of each other

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

[image: SCREENSHOT OF ARTBOARDS SITTING ON TOP OF EACH OTHER]

I have 3 artboards.  Two business card size. One larger A4.  One of the smaller Biz Card size artboards sits on the larger one even when I try to re-arrange them.  I have categorised them so each artwork components  are associated/attached  with the right artboard.
Two artboards do not seperate when I ask it to "rearrange artboards with artwork".
It doesn't matter what layout order I pick or space I suggest... it just keeps putting one of the smaller boards over the large one.
I have never had this problem before! Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

UPDATE: i have just moved them manually but would still love any feedback. :)

Comment: The system does not know what to do with the overlapping art, copy it or move it with whitch artboard so it does neither

Comment: I think the app actually assumes if you have overlapping artboards that is *intentional* and you *want* the overlap to be retained - because layer artwork would be in a specific position in relation to the artboards as they overlap..

Answer (score -1):

Distribution doesn't work too well in the entire Adobe suite, IF you attempt that with objects (or artboards) of different sizes.

I did not even know there's a tool to "rearrange" the artboards.

Just use the mouse and drag them around with the Artboard tool, use snapping if you need some alignment.